# Defining pointers to array of structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I came across this code:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *value;
} SPAM;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int num_spams;
    SPAM *spams;
} EGG;

SPAM my_spams[2] = {
    { "name1", "value1" },
    { "name2", "value2" },
};

EGG my_eggs[1] = {
    { "first egg", 1, my_spams }
};

EXPORT(int) getSPAMANDEGGS(EGG **eggs)
{
    *eggs = my_eggs;
    return 1;
}
```

In this declaration shouldn't the definition of EGG struct have SPAM **spams; as the definition of the spams member since we store an array of SPAMs there later?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers. So `SPAM *spams` can point to the first element of an array of `SPAM`.

Comment: Just like you can write `char foo[] = "abc"; char *foo_ptr = foo;`

Comment: `{ "first egg", 1, my_spams }` should be `{ "first egg", 2, my_spams }`, because `num_spams` should correspond to the number of elements in `my_spams` array, which is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not. An array of `SPAM` values is expressed through a single pointer, so `SPAM *spams` is correct.

The reason the parameter of the `getSPAMANDEGGS` function needs two asterisks is that it *sets* a pointer passed to it from the outside:

```
EGG *eggArray; // First asterisk is due to *
int eggArraySize = getSPAMANDEGGS(&eggArray); // Second asterisk is due to &
```

Without the `&` operator `getSPAMANDEGGS` would be unable to set a new value to `eggArray` pointer.